# how to Close p:accordionPanel on button click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, accordion

I am using  to enter address field .by default am setting active-index="-1" so the panel will be closed when the page gets loaded.After the details has been entered by user i want the panel area which means i want the accordion panel to be closed on button(save) click.but i tried a lot using java script but am not able to achieve ,and here is page

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="quotesForm">
                <div class="headerbg">
                    <div id="innerheaderbg">
                        <div id="iconarea">
                            <img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/headerimages/productlist.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="headertextarea">
                            <p class="headingtext">New Quote</p>
                            <p id="breadCrumbtext">Order &#160;<img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/error-bullet.gif" />
                                &#160;Quote List &#160;<img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/error-bullet.gif" />
                                &#160;New Quote
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <p:growl id="msgs" />


             <div class="widget widget-table action-table">
                <div class="widget-header" style="text-align:center;padding-top: 52px">
                    <h3>Create New Quote</h3>
                </div>  

                <div class="widget-content" style="background-color: #DAEDF4;height: 600px;"  >
                    <div id="calender" style="margin-left: 52px;margin-top: -26px">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <p:outputLabel id="qDate" value="#{quotesBean.qtCreationDate}"></p:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p:calendar id="popup" showOn="button" display="inline" >
                                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{quotesBean.onDateSelect}" update="qDate" />
                            </p:calendar>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Invoice # #{quotesBean.qCount}" style="margin-top:-15px;margin-left:10px;"/>
                    </div>

                <div id="company">
                    <table align="right" style="margin-right: 52px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;padding: 0;"><img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/favicon.ico"/><p:spacer width="5px"/>SolvEdge</th>
                            </tr>                   
                        </thead>
                        <tr><td style="text-align: center;padding: 0;">Zameen Pallavaram,</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="text-align: center;padding: 0;">Chennai,</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="text-align: center;padding: 0;">INDIA</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <h:form id="addForm">
                 <p:accordionPanel id="accordion" cache="false" activeIndex="-1" style="margin-bottom:20px;width:330px;" widgetVar="acc" >
                    <p:tab title="Bill To Address:" titleStyle="width:330px;background-color:#DAEDF4"  >
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Name" />  
                            <h:inputText value="#{quotesBean.name}"/>

                            <h:outputLabel value="Street" />  
                            <h:inputText value="#{quotesBean.street}"/>  

                            <h:outputLabel value="City" />  
                            <h:inputText value="#{quotesBean.city}"/>  

                            <h:outputLabel value="ZIP" />  
                            <h:inputText value="#{quotesBean.zip}"/>  
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save" value="Save" action="#{quotesBean.saveAddress}" update=":quotesForm:addForm:accordion" ajax="false" onclick="PF('quotesForm:addForm:accordion').hide();"/>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
                </h:form>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var link = document.getElementById('quotesForm:popup_input');
            link.style.display = 'none'; 

            function closeAccordianPanel()
            {
                var panel = document.getElementById('quotesForm:addForm:accordion');
                link.style.activeIndex = '-1'; 
                /* PF('widget_accordion').unselect(0); */
            }

            </script>
            </h:form>
            <br></br>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Note:Java Script i tried here is nothing worked for me,i would like to close the accordion panel on button click.

Comment: You btw have nested forms which is invalid in html and can cause weird and unexpected behaviour

Comment: @Kukeltje :  Yes i accept , your comment might helps other users. I asked on Feb 12 '15  and some how i matched my necessity at the time but i don't remember now.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have javascript errors in the console...(`PF('quotesForm:addForm:accordion').hide();` is wrong, it should be `PF('acc').hide();` IF it works at all (nothing about that in the PrimeFaces docs). And why close a ui component via javascript if you do an 'ajax="false"'. And sending a click event to the tab you want to toggle works, but even better is to use the official client-side api: `PF('acc').unselect(...);`

Ahhhh... you have additional code below the commandbutton... but there is a wrong widgetVar value... and it is commented out... and the other part does nothing...

Comment: Brother you are correct ,I have tried  'PF('acc').hide();' but doesn't work for me and i tried

Comment: PF('acc').unselect(-1);                                                                          but doesn't work for me , temporarily i have managed this by returning the same page on form(addForm) submit .But i want the toggle move to happen when button clicked.

Comment: But unselect (0) closes the open first tab… if you want to close other tabs to, you have to write some small jquery to detect which ones are open (detectableb by the presence of css classes)

Comment: '<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save" value="Save" onclick="PF('acc').unselect(0);"/>'

Answer (score 0):

Unselect(index of tab) method only hide the p:tab.

If you want to hide your accordionPanel, you can use rendered attribute.

Comment: please explain your answer in more detail.

Comment: The question was to close the accordion, not to hide it.

Comment: Your accordion only have one tab. If you want to collapse this tab, you use PF('acc').unselect(0)

Comment: @kerZyHart: <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save" value="Save" onclick="PF('acc').unselect(0);"/> works normally in my test project. Please check again.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the panel:

```
<p:panel id="toggleable" header="Toggleable" toggleable="true" 
                toggleOrientation="horizontal" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" 
                widgetVar="panel" class="left-menu-panel" >
</p:panel>
```

and button or commandLink which collapse panel

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="open-left-menu-button" 
                onclick="PF('panel').toggle()">
</p:commandLink>
```

You can set it with `toggleOrientation="horizontal/vertical"`.

normal panel - not collapsed:

[image: normal panel - not collapsed]

collapsed:

[image: collapsed]

Comment: The question is about an accordionPanel, not a panel!